# Expected number of moves to move balls to other bin

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> We have two bins, $A$ and $B$. Initially there are $3$ balls in bin $A$ and no balls in bin $B$. We proceed with a series of moves as follows: on each move, one of the three balls is randomly chosen, and it is moved from its bin to the other bin. What is the expected number of moves until the first time that all of the balls are simultaneously in bin $B$?

Here's what I've thought so far about this problem. We can use states to solve an expected value problem like this. Instead of calculating the probability for each state, we calculate the expected value if we start from that state.

But I'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be well-appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you choose randomly a bin, then take one ball from the bin, and put in the other bin, and redo the experience several times ?

Comment: Once you have clarified the rules of the game, just assign variables to the various states and work out the possible transitions.  For instance the state $(3,0)$ can only go to the state $(2,1)$ (if I have guessed the rules correctly) while $(2,1)$ can go either to $(1,2)$ or to $(3,0)$.

Comment: You have a Markov chain. There are essentially four states (e.g. number of balls in bin B) so you could let $X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the time to go from a state to $3$ in bin B.  You could then write thing like $E[X_1]=1+\frac13E[X_0]+\frac23E[X_2]$ and $E[X_3]=0$ and get four equations in four unknowns you can solve to find $E[X_0]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, this is a type of random walk problem with 4 states.
Let $p_i^{(n)}$ denote the probability of finding $i$ balls in A
after $n$ moves,
with $p_3^{(0)}=1$, $p_0^{(0)}=p_1^{(0)}=p_2^{(0)}=0$.
If you randomly chose a non-empty bin and move one of its balls
to the other bin, then
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_0^{(n+1)}\\ p_1^{(n+1)}\\ p_2^{(n+1)}\\ p_3^{(n+1)}
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac12 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & \frac12 & 0\\
0 & \frac12 & 0  & 1\\
0 & 0 & \frac12 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)
\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_0^{(n)}\\
p_1^{(n)}\\
p_2^{(n)}\\
p_3^{(n)}
\end{array}\right)$$
If otherwise the balls are chosen at random (which appears to be the OP's setup), multiples of $\frac13$ appear
in the matrix:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_0^{(n+1)}\\ p_1^{(n+1)}\\ p_2^{(n+1)}\\ p_3^{(n+1)}
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & \frac13 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & \frac23 & 0\\
0 & \frac23 & 0  & 1\\
0 & 0 & \frac13 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)
\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_0^{(n)}\\
p_1^{(n)}\\
p_2^{(n)}\\
p_3^{(n)}
\end{array}\right)$$

This is solved with the techniques of https://oeis.org/A102518/a102518.pdf .
The matrix $1-zA$ is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -z/3 & 0 & 0\\
-z & 1 & -2z/3 & 0\\
0 & -2z/3 & 1  & -z\\
0 & 0 & -z/3 & 1\\
\end{array}\right)
$$
Computing the inverse yields the generating functions
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_0(z)\\ p_1(z)\\ p_2(z)\\ p_3(z)
\end{array}\right)=
\frac{1}{9-10z^2+z^4}
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
9-7z^2 & z(3-z^2) & 2z^2 & 2z^3\\
3z(3-z^2) & 3(3-z^2) & 6z & 6z^2\\
6z^2 & 6z & 3(3-z^2)  & 3z(3-z^2)\\
2z^3 & 2z^2 & z(3-z^2) & 9-7z^2\\
\end{array}\right)
\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_0^{(0)}\\
p_1^{(0)}\\
p_2^{(0)}\\
p_3^{(0)}
\end{array}\right)
$$
and because only $p_3^{(0)}$ is nonzero
$$
=
\frac{1}{9-10z^2+z^4}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2z^3\\
6z^2\\
3z(3-z^2)\\
9-7z^2
\end{array}\right)
$$
We are interested in the probabilities that no balls are in A after $n$ moves,
$$
p_0(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}p_0^{(n)}z^n = \frac{2z^3}{9-10z^2+z^4}
$$
$$
=\frac{2}{9}z^3+\frac{20}{81}z^5+\frac{182}{729}z^7+\cdots
$$
$$
=2z\left(1\frac{z^2}{3^2}+10\frac{z^4}{3^4}+91\frac{z^6}{3^6}+820\frac{z^8}{3^8}+\cdots\right)
$$
where the coefficients can be taken from https://oeis.org/A002452
$$
=2z\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{9^n-1}{8} \cdot \frac{z^{2n}}{3^{2n}}
$$
So the probability of finding all balls simultaneously in B is zero if the number of moves is even, and the probability is
$P_{2n+1}\equiv (3^{2n}-1)/(4\times 3^{2n})$ if the number of moves is $2n+1$.
Note that this is the probability in the cases where moves are continued, even after that $p_0^{(n)}$ state
has passed, so the remaining problem is a termination problem: to compute with the inclusion-execlusion principle the
probability of reaching that state the first time (!) after $n$ moves, avoiding the moves where
that state was reached in less than $n$ moves.
The probability of being in state $p_0^{(n)}$ after $n$ moves after starting from state $p_0^{(0)}=1$ would
be represented by the upper left entry in the inverse matrix: $q(z) = (9-7z^2)/(9-10z^2+z^4)=1+z^2/3+7z^4/27+\cdots$.
$q(z)-1$ gives the probability of returning to state $p_0^{(n)}$ after $n$ moves.
$p_0(z)$ represents the cases reaching $p_0$ after $n$ steps without moving through $p_0$ in between,
reaching $p_0$ after $n'$ steps to $p_0$ and $n-n'$ steps described by $q$, or moving through
$n''$ steps o $p_0$, $n'$ steps again to $p_0$ and $n-n'-n''$ steps to the state. This sort of convolution
of probabilities is represented by products of the generating functions (see e.g. the book by Flajolet and Sedgewick).
Let $\bar p_0(z)$ denote the generating function for first time passages through state $p_0$, then
$$
% p_0(z) = \bar p_0(z)+ \bar p_0(z)[q(z)-1]+ \bar p_0(z) [q(z)-1]^2+ \bar p_0(z)[q(z)-1]^3+\cdots = \frac{\bar p_0(z)}{1-q(z)}
p_0(z) = \bar p_0(z)+ \bar p_0(z)[q(z)-1]= \bar p_0(z) q(z) 
$$
Therefore
$$
\bar p_0(z) = p_0(z)/q(z) = \frac{2z^3}{9-7z^2} = 6(z/3)^3\sum_{n\ge 0} [7 (z/3)^2]^n = \frac{2}{9}z^3+\frac{14}{81}z^5+\frac{98}{72
9}z^7+\cdots
$$
So the probability of being in state $p_0$ for the first time is $6\times 7^n/3^{2n+3}$ after $2n+3$ steps, zero if the number of steps is even. The expected number of moves is
$$
\frac{2}{9}\times 3+\frac{14}{81}\times 5 + \cdots = \sum_{n\ge 0} 6\frac{7^n}{3^{3n+3}}\times (2n+3)=10.
$$